# re-run custom Modernizr test

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I have a test which will change depending on certain user interactions. I'm trying to tie this into modernizr.

I'm trying to force a test to re-run by calling addTest again.

```
//this works the first time
//adds html.mousing class
Modernizr.addTest('mousing',function(){
    return true;
});


//later in the code
//this DOES NOT add html.no-mousing
Modernizr.addTest('mousing',function(){
    return false;
});
```

Any ideas how to rerun or refresh a modernizer test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modernizr is made to test browser functionality not arbitrarily toggle classes based on user interactions. (Just because a user has interacted with your page *does not mean the browser is all of a sudden incapable of "mousing"*). You are better off not adding this as a Modernizr test and simply adding/remove classnames when you need to.

However, to answer your question, you would need to delete the cached value of mousing on `Modernizr` and re-run the test while additionally manually removing any matching classnames on the html element. Something like:

```
Modernizr.addTest('mousing',function(){
  return true;
});
/* ... */
delete Modernizr.mousing;
Modernizr.addTest('mousing',function(){
  document.html.className = document.html.className.replace(/\b(no-)?mousing\b/g, '');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I agree the technique isn't in the core objective of Modernizer- detecting a browsers ability,. Plus the technique to replace the class isn't pretty. I did however, want to piggy back on the built in functionalities of Modernizer, the class injection, loading as early as possible etc.  I guess I'll look at betters ways of implementation.